# Entire data frame is not displayed while using kable() in R

Tags: r, kable

I am trying to display a data frame using `kable` function. The dataframe consists of 29 columns but only 9 columns are displayed and the remaining columns are repeated.

The dataframe used is

```
structure(list(Name = c("Grand Total", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"
), GrandTotal = c(3416, 297, 410, 326, 125, 29), English = c(1096, 
18, 64, 0, 55, 0), Science = c(211, 5, 39, 0, 55, 0), Language = c(149, 
5, 0, 0, 10, 0), Maths = c(22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Social = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), English = c(211, 5, 39, 0, 55, 0), Science = c(149, 
5, 0, 0, 10, 0), Maths = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Social = c(22, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), English = c(1096, 18, 64, 0, 55, 0), Science = c(211, 
5, 39, 0, 55, 0), Language = c(149, 5, 0, 0, 10, 0), Maths = c(22, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Social = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), English = c(211, 
5, 39, 0, 55, 0), Science = c(149, 5, 0, 0, 10, 0), ACIntern = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), PAM = c(22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Maths = c(1096, 18, 
64, 0, 55, 0), Social = c(211, 5, 39, 0, 55, 0), English = c(149, 
5, 0, 0, 10, 0), Science = c(22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Language = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Maths = c(211, 5, 39, 0, 55, 0), Social = c(149, 
5, 0, 0, 10, 0), English = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Science = c(22, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

The code used for displaying the data frame as a table format is as follows

```
monthSelected <- c("April","May","June")

month1 <- paste0(monthSelected[1],' ',yearSelected)
month2 <- paste0(monthSelected[2],' ',yearSelected)
month3 <- paste0(monthSelected[3],' ',yearSelected)

myHeader <- c(" " = 2, month1 = 9, month2 = 9, month3 = 9)    
names(myHeader) <- c(" ", month1, month2, month3)
kable(df[1:ncol(df)],"html") %>%
  kable_styling(c("striped", "bordered")) %>%
  add_header_above(c(" "=2, "IND" = 5, "US" = 4,"IND" = 5, "US" = 4,"IND" = 5, "US" = 4)) %>%
  add_header_above(header = myHeader)
```

The output displayed is as follows

[image]

I can't figure out where I went wrong. Can anyone help me out with this issue?
In addition to it, is it possible to freeze first two columns when the table is scrolled horizontally?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. In order to help you, it's very important we can reproduce the problem you have. For that purpose, it's key to have a small sample of your data. Maybe `dput(head(YourData))`. Also, you may want to see package `datatable`, I doubt you'll be able to scroll a table made with `kable`

Comment: I have updated the sample data frame. The column name gets changed when displaying in `kable()`. Can you provide some suitable inputs